# What does 176 mean in Linux magic SysRq key

Tags: networking, kernel, security

Here is the value set in `Ubuntu 22.04`:

```
root@test:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
176
```

I can't find the value from this link:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html

What does it mean?

Comment: The link you provided has the table; read 176 not as a *decimal* number but as a *binary* number using the table you provided  (ie. each *bit* has that option turned *ON* or *OFF*).

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-all-sysrq-functions-on-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For interpretation of the SysReq value you need to convert it into binary,
then check which 'bits' are `1` telling whether the corresponding function is enabled.

Typing e.g.

```
$ python -c 'print( bin(176) )'
0b10110000
```

... at the bash prompt will tell the bits prepended with a `0b` (for "binary").
Note: start from the right with the value `1` for the first bit, then `2` for the next, doubling the value for each step left.

If you wish to have the actual bitvalues printed, then it requires some more code;

```
$ cat cvt.py 
#!/bin/env python

import sys

b=bin(int(sys.argv[1])).replace("0b","")
v=2**(len(b)-1)
for bit in b: 
  print( f"{v:>4}", "bit" if bit=="1" else "bit, not included" )
  v=v//2
```

which executed shows this:

```
$ python cvt.py 176
 128 bit
  64 bit, not included
  32 bit
  16 bit
   8 bit, not included
   4 bit, not included
   2 bit, not included
   1 bit, not included
```

So, `176` means that

```
 16 =  0x10 - enable sync command
 32 =  0x20 - enable remount read-only
128 =  0x80 - allow reboot/poweroff
```

... functions are enabled.

*Note: 16+32+128 = 176*

```
$ echo ' 16+32+128' | bc
176
```